# Content-Disposition - an invalid character was found in the mail header: '['

Tags: c#, filenames, content-disposition, formatexception

I want to get filename from the url below. When parsing Content-Disposition header to extract the filename it throws an error `System.FormatException: An invalid character was found in the mail header: '['.` .The value of the header is like below. I don't want to replace these characters because the filename will be changed if I do. How can I fix it?

```
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename*=UTF-8''[Saglamindir.net] Internet Download Manager.rar
Url: https://www17.zippyshare.com/d/qS76ZdES/29289/%5bSaglamindir.net%5d%20Internet%20Download%20Manager.rar
```

**My Code:**

```
var cdHeader = response.Headers["Content-Disposition"];
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(cdHeader))
{
    var properFormat = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(Encoding.GetEncoding(1252).GetBytes(cdHeader));
    properFormat = HttpUtility.UrlDecode(properFormat);
    var disp = new ContentDisposition(properFormat);
    var temp = disp.FileName;
    return temp.ReplaceInvalidChars();
}
```

Comment: Neither of the RFCs that specify the Content-Disposition format (https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1806.txt and https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2183.txt) outlaw that character, and it's legal in a Windows file name.  It's an odd file name, but it appears legal

Answer (score 0):

You can't use unescaped "[" or "]" here (they need percent-encoding). The relevant specs are RFC 6266 (Content-Disposition) and RFC 8187.

Comment: When I tried without decoding the url (with percent-encoding), ContentDisposition.FileName was null. What is the right way to do it?